# Tuning fork examination - Bing's test

Tags: ear, otolaryngology, audiology, inner-ear, middle-ear

In Russian medical segment the concept of Bing's test is formulated in such manner ("Otolaryngology: A Manual in Two Volumes", ISBN: 978-5-388-00664-6): There are two pathways in conduction of Bing test - "classical" and "modern". In the "classical" case they measure **Tb** (time elapsed since the active tuning fork was placed on mastoid process to the complete absence of sound sensation) when external acoustic meatus (EAM) is occluded and intact respectively.

It's assumed that **Tb,occluded** > **Tb,open** is a sign of the normal hearing or weak sensorineuroal hearing loss i.e. Bing-positive **Tb,occluded** = **Tb,open** means conductive deafeness or Bing-negative. Authors also pointed out that "modern" case is that the tuning fork is also placed on the mastoid process and after the ceasation of sound perception patient is asked to close the EAM. If sound is returned they consider this as normal hearing or weak SNHL, if not - as conductive deafeness.

English textbooks provide some different explanation of this test. For example, in Diseases of Ear, Nose and Throat by Dhingra, one could meet:

> ... normal person or one with sensorineural hearing loss hears *louder* when ear canal is occluded and softer when it's open (Bing posisitive)...no change (Bing negative).

It is worth noting that Dhingra explains it in terms of loudness and not in terms of duration. Also, I came across [an article written by L Csovanyos](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/13882548/), where the original method of conducting the test was mentioned; this original method turned out to be the previously described  as "modern" by russian authors.

So I'm intrested in the following:

(i) What is the most complete interpretation that could describe the methodology of this test?

(ii) Maybe duration is a stronger characteristic than loudness? Loudness may depend on more factors of the patient's organism than duration.

Comment: I'm sorry this question isn't getting an answer. I'd give it a go, but I was never taught about Bing's test (I'm in the US.) We were taught to do hearing evaluations using a combination of Weber, Rinne tests and whispered word.

Comment: So we do. But the extended examination implies Bing's test also. We'll see what it goes for that.

Comment: My understanding is that the three tests I do will detect all the kinds of hearing loss. Heaven knows I'm not an otologist.